# Button to show panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, panel

When I try to bring up a panel when a button is pressed it does not show up. In properties visible is set to false. I bring up the panel the first time using this method:

```
        pnlSettings.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        pnlSettings.Size = this.ClientSize;
        pnlSettings.Visible = true;
        pnlSettings.BringToFront();
```

That code works the first time it is used. But when I try use the same code elsewere in the program it does not fully work.

```
        private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int valueTemp;

        valueTemp = _game.Settings.GetValue("MusicVolume", 2);
        if (valueTemp < 0) valueTemp = 0;
        if (valueTemp > 3) valueTemp = 3;
        trackMusic.Value = valueTemp;
        valueTemp = _game.Settings.GetValue("SoundFxVolume", 3);
        if (valueTemp < 0) valueTemp = 0;
        if (valueTemp > 3) valueTemp = 3;
        trackSoundFx.Value = valueTemp;

        pnlSettings.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        pnlSettings.Size = this.ClientSize;
        pnlSettings.Visible = true;
        pnlSettings.BringToFront();

        this.Menu = mnuTitleSettings;
    }
```

The code above works how it's supposed to. However the following code just pauses the game and changes the menu. The panel settings panel does not show up.

```
        private void mnuMain_Settings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int valueTemp;

        Pause(true);

        valueTemp = _game.Settings.GetValue("MusicVolume", 2);
        if (valueTemp < 0) valueTemp = 0;
        if (valueTemp > 3) valueTemp = 3;
        trackMusic.Value = valueTemp;
        valueTemp = _game.Settings.GetValue("SoundFxVolume", 3);
        if (valueTemp < 0) valueTemp = 0;
        if (valueTemp > 3) valueTemp = 3;
        trackSoundFx.Value = valueTemp;

        pnlSettings.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        pnlSettings.Size = this.ClientSize;
        pnlSettings.Visible = true;
        pnlSettings.BringToFront();


        this.Menu = mnuSettings;
    }
```

Is there another way that I can display the the panel and it still save and change the data? Or is there something I can add to make it display? I have tried adding

```
        pnlSettings.Show();
```

Still no luck.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control doesn't become visible until you add it to the parent's Control collection.

```
    pnlSettings.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    pnlSettings.Size = this.ClientSize;
    this.Controls.Add(pnlSettings);
```

Don't forget to call its Dispose() method when you remove it again.

Comment: Well then why did the same code in `btnSettings_click` work? It wasn't adding the panel to `Controls` either.

Comment: I have no idea. My original code still works were I said it did. And Hans amendment made the code work for the second button.

Comment: @user662973: you probably had already added the panel somewhere else, in code or in the designer.

Comment: Yes, well realised. I added the panel in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code elsewhere that removes `pnlSettings` from its parent's `Controls` collection?  Something like:

```
this.Controls.Remove(pnlSettings);
```

Comment: No. There is nothing removing the panel